# problema de conteo en excel

Tags: vba

expertos tengo un problema con esta macro, la ejecuto pero el resultado en cada celda es uno de mas;como puedo mejorarla en todas las columnas de color naranja 
la macro termina su conteo hasta la ultima celda en blanco de la columnas "a;d"y quiero que termine su conteo hasta el ultimo numero de la columna "a;d" gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Sub NoSalenDesde()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("G16:N25").ClearContents
For x = 0 To 9
   Range("G" & x + 16) = x
   Range("I" & x + 16) = x
   Range("K" & x + 16) = x
   Range("M" & x + 16) = x
Next
'--
For x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 99 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Range("H" & 16 + Range("A" & x)) = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - x + 1
   Range("J" & 16 + Range("B" & x)) = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - x + 1
   Range("L" & 16 + Range("C" & x)) = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - x + 1
   Range("N" & 16 + Range("D" & x)) = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - x + 1
Next
'--
Range("G16:H25").Sort Key1:=Columns("H"), Key2:=Columns("G"), Order1:=xlDescending
Range("I16:J25").Sort Key1:=Columns("J"), Key2:=Columns("I"), Order1:=xlDescending
Range("K16:L25").Sort Key1:=Columns("L"), Key2:=Columns("K"), Order1:=xlDescending
Range("M16:N25").Sort Key1:=Columns("N"), Key2:=Columns("M"), Order1:=xlDescending
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el segundo `for` sobra el `+1`

```
For x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 99 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Range("H" & 16 + Range("A" & x)) = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - x
   Range("J" & 16 + Range("B" & x)) = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - x
   Range("L" & 16 + Range("C" & x)) = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - x
   Range("N" & 16 + Range("D" & x)) = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - x
Next
```

Comment: Éxitos con el premio! :D

Comment: gracias por la respuesta

Comment: funciono? Puede marcar mi respuesta como respuesta del post estoy trabajando en mi reputación gracias :)

Comment: como hago eso master

Comment: al lado de mi respuesta hay un cero con dos flechas y abajo hay un chulo. solo es dar click al chulo y listo :)

Comment: le agradezco si tiene una solucion a mi otra preguinta gracias

Comment: Claro que si!, no la he visto, pero déjeme la reviso este fin de semana a ver que tal.

Comment: es la pregunta mas reciente